# VirtualBox configuration NAT and Bridge Adapter

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridge

'm using VirtualBox and created a Virtual Machine that runs Ubuntu 20.04. I've created a simple flask server that accepts HTTPS requests and does some processing on the data before connecting to another server in the internet to send and receive information. This is what happens:

1. If I use 'Bridge Adapter' on the virtual machine I can communicate from my laptop where the virtual machine is installed to the virtual machine no problem but the virtual machine cannot send/receive requests to the server on the internet. (if I do an ifconfig I get an IP of: 192.168.xx.xx)
2. If I use the 'NAT' adapter option. Then the opposite is true. The virtual machine can communicate with the server in the internet but I cannot communicate with the virtual machine from my laptop where the virtual machine is installed (if I do an ifconfig I get an IP like 10.0.x.x)

My question is. Is there an option that needs to be configured so that I can have both options 1. and 2. from above? where I can communicate with the virtual machine and the virtual machine can communicate to the server in the internet?

Comment: Did you install the Virtual Box Extensions?  https://linuxconfig.org/virtualbox-extension-pack-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: What's the default route in the VM when using bridged mode?

Comment: @stickybit Not sure.  How do I check that?

Comment: https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-find-default-gateway-in-linux/ or https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-default-gateway-in-ubuntu/ or ...